# Prove that regular values are dense (Brown-Sard Theorem), is true by showing it is true for an open subset.

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

I don't believe this is necessarily related to cohomology. This could be something about manifolds in general.

My book is From Calculus to Cohomology by Ib Madsen and Jørgen Tornehave.

[image]

I. The claim appears to be that if the Brown-Sard Theorem is true for some open subset of $M$ that is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^{\dim(M)}$, then the Brown-Sard Theorem is true for the whole of $M$. I guess the $\mathbb R^n$ should be $\mathbb R^m$ instead.

Question: Is there some general idea behind this claim to prove this claim succinctly?

II. I know you can't just spoonfeed me the answer, and I have 2 ways of proving this, but both of them are very long. I hope this is enough effort so that I may be provided a general idea behind the claim or if there is none, to be provided an idea of how to prove this claim.

- Way 1. The first way involves guessing that

  - Step 1.1. if the Brown-Sard Theorem is true for some open subset of $M$ that is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^{\dim(M)}$, then the Brown-Sard Theorem is true for every open subset of $M$ that is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^{\dim(M)}$.
  - Step 1.2. if the Brown-Sard Theorem is true for every open subset of $M$ that is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^{\dim(M)}$, then the Brown-Sard Theorem is true for the whole of $M$.
  - In Step 1.1 I consider the diffeomorphism between $V$ and $W$, open sets in $M$ that are both diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^{\dim(M)}$ and hope that $f^{-1}(V)$ and $f^{-1}(W)$ are diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^{\dim(N)}$ and thus each other or are at least diffeomorphic to each other anyway. In Step 1.2, I use that the closure of unions contains the union of closures.
- Way 2. Here, I prove a contrapositive. If there is some neighborhood $V_p$ of some $p \in M$ such that $V_p  \cap \{\text{regular values of } \ f: N \to M \} = \emptyset$, then for the neighborhood $U_p$ of $p$ that is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$ and thus diffeomorphic to $W$, we have that there is a neighborhood $X_q$ of $q = \varphi(p)$, where $\varphi$ is the diffeomorphism from $U_p$ to $W$, such that $X_q \cap \{\text{regular values of } \ g: f^{-1}(W) \to W \} = \emptyset$, where

  - $g = \tilde{h}: f^{-1}(W) \to W$ is the induced map of $h = f \circ \iota = f|_{f^{-1}(W)} : f^{-1}(W) \to M$, $\iota: f^{-1}(W) \to N$ where $\tilde{h}(a) = h(a)$ for all $a \in f^{-1}(W)$, and
  - $\tilde{h}$ is smooth because $f \circ \iota$ is smooth and $W$ is a regular submanifold of $M$

    - $W$ is a regular submanifold of $M$ because $W$ is open in $M$.
    - $f \circ \iota$ is smooth because $\iota$ is smooth because $f^{-1}(W)$ is a regular submanifold of $N$ because $f^{-1}(W)$ is open in $N$.
  - Specifically, the $X_q$ is I think $\varphi(U_p \cap V_p)$ or something.

III. Given the length of and possible errors in my 2 aforementioned ways, I think I'm missing something obvious.

This seems to be related to

1. how an [earlier lemma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1qV1.png) was proved. It seems that

   - Step 1 was that the lemma was true for $M = \mathbb R^{\dim(M)}$ and then
   - Step 2 was that if Step 1 holds, then the lemma is true for every open subset of $M$ diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^{\dim(M)}$ and then
   - Step 3 was that if the conclusion of Step 2 holds, then the lemma is true for the whole of $M$.

I think the idea of replacing $M$ by $W$, in the Brown-Sard Theorem (Theorem 11.5), is similar to the above Step 3.

2. how a proposition in An Introduction to Manifolds by Loring W. Tu is proved ([Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onU2H.png). [Proposition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLVFF.png).). The proof involves "open condition" or "[Open property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_topology#O)", and the proposition is about sufficient conditions for an immersion or submersion to have constant rank.

I suspect the general idea is that to prove something is true for a manifold, we can prove it is true for some or for every open subset of the manifold that is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^{\dim(\text{the manifold})}$

Answer (score 3):

They're not claiming that the theorem being true for ***some*** open subset that's diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^m$ implies that it's true for $M$. What's closer to the truth is that if the theorem is true for ***every*** open subset that's diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^m$, then it's true for $M$.

Actually, if you read further down the page, you'll see that what they're actually proving is that something stronger is true for every open subset diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^m$: If $U\subseteq M$ is such a subset, then almost all points in the codomain are regular values of $f|_U$, or equivalently, the set of singular values of $f|_U$ has measure zero. (It follows from this that the set of regular values of $f|_U$ is dense, but it's stronger than that.) Then they explain that you can cover $M$ with countably many such subsets, and use the fact that the union of countably many sets of measure zero again has measure zero.