# $f : M \longmapsto N \hspace{0.1cm} C^{\infty}$ if dim $M > $dim $N$ then $f$ can't be injective

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

Is the statement true ? Let's suppose $M,N$ be smooth-manifolds without boundary for the moment, I think I got the proof if I'm able to find $y \in \text{RegVal}(f) \cap \text{Im}(f)$ arguing as follows : by the sake of contradiction let's $f$ be injective, then $f^{-1}(y) = \left\lbrace x\right\rbrace$, but for a known theorem $f^{-1} (y)$ is an $(m-n)$ manifold.

Since $m > n$, we have that this can't happens since $\left\lbrace x\right\rbrace$ is a $0-$manifold.

This seems correct, but I can always find some $y \in \text{RegVal}(f) \cap \text{Im}(f) ?$ And what if boundaries are allowed ?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Doesn't this follow from Sard's theorem?

Comment: @ThePuix Coud you add some details ?

Comment: If $f$ is a smooth map, then the set of critical values of $f$ is of measure zero. I guess it is not clear that the image of $f$ cannot be of measure zero also. I guess this is where you need the dimension assumption.

Comment: I don't know whether this approach works, but do you know the rank theorem?

Comment: @Thorgott Yes, but I don't see how it follows from that

Comment: Every function has locally constant rank somewhere and looking at the normal given given by the rank theorem there reveals that the function cannot be injective.

Comment: @Thorgott But how this implies that $y \in \text{RegVal}(f) \cap \text{Im}(f)$ always exists ?

Comment: It doesn't. As I said, I don't know whether your approach works or not. This is just an alternative approach to at least see that the claim is true.

Comment: @Thorgott The claim is true even for $C^0$ functions, but I'd like to see a proof without using Brouwer open map Theorem

Comment: Apparently Sard's theorem is stronger than I remember: The set of regular values of $f$ is _dense_ in $N$, so you can certianly pick such a $y$ and your proof goes through.

Comment: @ThePuix Why? Is Im$f$ open in $N$ ?

Comment: The crux of your argument is a regular value for $f$. If the set of regular values is dense, it is in particular non-empty, so you can pick a regular value for $f$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3186332/prove-that-regular-values-are-dense-brown-sard-theorem-is-true-by-showing-it)

Comment: @ThePuix Of course I can pick a regular value for $f$, but every point not in the image will be a regular value as well, but it just can't help if I pick one of those

Comment: It also follows from the constant rank theorem, as then $df = v^{-1} \circ f \circ u$ with $v,u$ diffeomorphisms, so as $df$ cannot be injective, neither can $f$.

Comment: Wait, are points outside of the image regular values?

Comment: @ThePuix Sure, $f^{-1}(y) = \emptyset$ and what you should verify true empty

Comment: Alright, then I don't know how use Sard's theorem to see this.

Comment: @ThePuix Yes, neither do I.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you most certainly cannot always find a regular value in the image of $f$. Consider the map $\Bbb R^m\to\Bbb R^n$ (with $m>n$) given by
$$f(x_1,\dots,x_n,x_{n+1},\dots,x_m) = (x_1,\dots,x_{n-1},0).$$
That said, this map has constant rank and certainly will not be injective.
In fact, even though $f$ may not be a submersion, in a neighborhood of a point of *maximum rank* the rank of $f$ will be constant and the map will, in appropriate coordinates, look like such a mapping. Thus, it fails to be injective in a neighborhood of any point of maximum rank. Where the rank drops, things get much more difficult. But this is still enough to answer your question.